# how to customize and display the frame window at center of my screen in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hi I am developing an desktop application using swing when i am executing the frame window it is displaying at the left side bottom of my screen can i customize that and display at in center of the screen?

Comment: `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)`?

Comment: actually i cant able to edit the generated code confused to insert this code

Comment: Are you using GUI Builder?

Comment: yes i am using gui builder am setting all the properties through that only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "yes i am using gui builder"

Just put `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` after `initComponents()`, in the constructor.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

---

`JFrame` as a subclass of `Window` inherits `Window` methods. The API can be seen [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) The method used above is listed as follows

- [`public void setLocationRelativeTo(Component c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) - Sets the location of the window relative to the specified component according to the following scenarios.
  **If the component is null, or the GraphicsConfiguration associated with this component is null, the window is placed in the center of the screen.**

Comment: For frame positioning, you cannot go by `setLocationByPlatform(true)`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) for demo.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson is your comment worded correctly? I'm a bit confused by it and its implication :/

Comment: Well, it presumed, *"No **don't** set it in the middle of the screen, that looks so 'Splash Screenish'! Instead.."* was understood.

Comment: @AndrewThompson _"you cannot go by setLocationByPlatform(true)"_ .. Did you mean "you **can**" ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, *"cannot go by"* means *"cannot pass up"* or *"cannot do without"*.  :P

Answer (score 0):

Following Code will provide you Width and Height of Your Screen

`Toolkit toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();`

`toolkit.getScreenSize().width`

`toolkit.getScreenSize().height`

Then Using This Height and Width You can set where to position Your frame with following function

`this.setLocation(int x, int y)`

//first variable x is position relative to left top of ur screen in horizontal direction

// second variable  y is position relative to left top in vertical direction